Followed Posts in Staging Ground don't show up in profile
I'm following a post in Staging Ground:

It works as I've already gotten a notification about a new comment. But when I go to
my profile page it states that I don't follow any posts:

Is this a bug or do I just look at the wrong place?

Those are not the only two options. The third option is not implemented yet and the fourth option is working as intended. Other things don't transfer from staging ground to main site as well currently. Close votes used to be one I believe, I'm not sure if that has been changed now.

This was already reported in the beta and is currently marked [status-review].
